# Remove line and column with number N from two-dimensional List

Tags: c#

I have a two-dimensional list:

```
List<List<double>> dests = new List<List<double>>();
List<double> s_1 = new List<double>() { 0, 5, 0.5, 2 };
List<double> s_2 = new List<double>() { 5, 0, 1, 0.6 };
List<double> s_3 = new List<double>() { 0.5, 1, 0, 2.5 };
List<double> s_4 = new List<double>() { 2, 0.6, 2.5, 0 };
dests.Add(s_1);
dests.Add(s_2);
dests.Add(s_3);
dests.Add(s_4);
```

This list of list is always square matrix. I need to remove from this matrix column and line with number N. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Surely you mean column OR line with number N?

Comment: I need to remove column with index N and line with index N at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest is -

```
dests.RemoveAt(N); // removes the line (row)

foreach(var list in dests) // removes column by going through each row 
 list.RemoveAt(N);
```